# Removes duplicate lines from files recursively

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I have a directory with bunch of csv files. I want to remove the duplicates lines from all the files.

I have tried awk solution but seems to be bit tedious to do it for each and every file.

`awk '!x[$0]++' file.csv`

Even if I will do 
`awk '!x[$0]++' *`

I will lost the file names. Is there a way to remove duplicates from all the files using just one command or script.

Just to clarify 
If there are 3 files in the directory, then the output should contain 3 files, each sorted independently. After running the command or script the same folder should contain 3 files each with unique entries.

Comment: do you want to modify files in place OR to create the new files?

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in dir/*; 
do awk '!a[$0]++' "$f" > "$f.uniq"; 
done
```

to overwrite the existing files change to: `awk '!a[$0]++' "$f" > "$f.uniq" && mv "$f.uniq" "$f"` after testing!

Answer (score 0):

This will create new files, with suffix `.new`, that have only unique lines:

```
gawk '!x[$0]++{print>(FILENAME".new")}' *.csv
```

How it works

- `!x[$0]++`

  This is a condition.  It evaluates to true only the current line, `$0`, has not been seen before.
- `print >(FILENAME".new")`

  If the condition evaluates to true, then this print statement is executed.  It writes the current line to a file whose name is the name of the current file, `FILENAME`, followed by the string `.new`.

Comment: An unparenthesized expression on the right side of output redirection is undefined behavior per POSIX so YMMV depending on the awk version you're using. Use `print>FILENAME".new"` instead. Also, if you have a lot if input files then you'll have to close the output files as you go or you'll get a "too many open files" error from some awks. Or just say this is gawk-specific and don't worry about any of it :-).

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for "inplace" editing and automatic open/close management of output files:

```
awk -i inplace '!seen[FILENAME,$0]++' *.csv
```